# Accessing ith array within a javascript object

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm following a book with the following code, I can't seem to make the lines between the circles show up. It seems to be because if I do

```
drawLine(context, 1, 1, 100, 100, 3);
```

it works, however if I do:

```
drawLine(context, untangleGame.circles[1].x, 1, 100, 100, 3);
```

It wont work. So my question is how do I access that value. This is an example from a book which used jQuery for this.

It is for this bit of code, which draws a line from the first circle to every other circle, it then iterates over the other circles:

```
for (var i = 0; i < untangleGame.circles.length; i++) {
    var startPoint = untangleGame.circles[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        var endPoint = untangleGame.circles[j];
        drawLine(context, startPoint.x, startPoint.y, endPoint.x, endPoint.y, 1);
        untangleGame.lines.push(new Line(startPoint, endpoint,
        untangleGame.thinLineThickness));
    }
}
```

I have the example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/5wdjpryo/

The game I'm trying to follow is called untangle.

Comment: Nothing in the fiddle fills in `untangleGame.circles`, so the loop doesn't do anything.

Comment: Have you tried this in a debugger?  It took me almost no time to find that line and see why it didn't work.

Comment: hahaha, Yeah that was stupid of me. I missed the untangleGame.circles.push(new Circle(x,y,circleRadius)); line in the circle loop, however new it just draws 1 random circle.

Comment: Ah well, the plot's given away.  The point is that there's nothing in the code posted here that demonstrates the problem.  (There might be other issues with the code, but that's for another day.)

Comment: No, I don't know how to debug really. Any recommendations? I don't program particularity just messing around.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Yeah I'm just going by a book, 90% of it isn't my work, other than not using jQuery.

Comment: Running in most modern web browsers give you debugging tools for free.  Try hitting F12 in Chrome, Firefox, or even IE, and you will get a collection of tools.  Each is a little different, and the Chrome and Firefox ones are significantly better than the IE ones (I don't know about IE>9; it might have changed.)  Find the Javascript tab in the tools window and you can open your code, set breakpoints, examine and alter variables, step through line-by-line, and in some, even change code live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to initialize your untangleGame object, see this update http://jsfiddle.net/5wdjpryo/1/
Basically add `var c = new Circle(x, y); untangleGame.circles.push(c);` when you draw circles.

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById('game');

    // canvas height and width:
    var width = canvas.width;
    var height = canvas.height;

    function Circle(x, y, radius) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }



    var context = canvas.getContext && canvas.getContext('2d');

    function drawCircle(context, x, y, radius) {
        context.fillStyle = 'green';
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();
    }

    drawCircle(context, 100, 100, 10);

    // draw random 5 circles:
    var circleRadius = 10;
    var circlesCount = 5;

        // the game object:
    var untangleGame = {
        circles: [],
        thinLineThickness: 1,
        lines: []
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < circlesCount; i++) {
        var x = Math.random() * width;
        var y = Math.random() * height;
        var c = new Circle(x, y);
        untangleGame.circles.push(c);
        drawCircle(context, x, y, 10);
    }

    // drawing line and line object:
    function Line(startPoint, endpoint, thickness) {
        this.startPoint = startPoint;
        this.endPoint = endPoint;
        this.thickness = thickness;
    }




    function drawLine(context, x1, y1, x2, y2, thickness) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(x1, y1);
        context.lineTo(x2, y2);
        context.lineWidth = thickness;
        context.strokeStyle = "#cfc";
        context.stroke();
    }

    // checking that drawLine works
    drawLine(context, 1, 1, 100, 100, 3);

    for (var i = 0; i < untangleGame.circles.length; i++) {
        var startPoint = untangleGame.circles[i];
        for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            var endPoint = untangleGame.circles[j];
            drawLine(context, startPoint.x, startPoint.y, endPoint.x, endPoint.y, 1);
            untangleGame.lines.push(new Line(startPoint, endPoint,
            untangleGame.thinLineThickness));
        }
    }
```